# Bumblebee Screwed Up Unity. Can't Even do a Reinstall to Get it Back

Tags: unity, 13.04, nvidia, xorg, bumblebee

I have a MacBook Pro 6,2 with both Intel integrated graphics and Nvidia 330M. I was trying to get my external monitor to work in order to extend my display, but the proprietary drivers just gave me a black screen. I then looked into solutions for hybrid graphics. Not knowing if it was right for my computer, I took the risk and installed Bumblebee. It messed up everything, even after I did a purge. Now I just get text-only mode, where it asks for my login/password and then just goes into shell mode. Typing startx at the prompt produces an error, as well as typing "unity"

Here is my Xorg.0.log:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/5955911/

The live CD works fine. This used to work fine before I installed Bumblebee. I even tried doing a fresh install, and it still gave me these results. So far I have tried:

- Forcing nouveau drivers by creating a folder and following directions at the end of http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/InstallNouveau/.
- Using an older kernel from GRUB
- Purging Nvidia drivers
- Reinstalling/updating Intel drivers

Answer (score 0):

purge nvidia driver. it should come unity back.

---

Edit:
purge xorg conf file( /etc/X11/xorg.conf) and install intel driver `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel`

Comment: Already tried that also. Didn't work.

Comment: i edited my answer

Comment: Still didn't work. I have the latest version of the drviers.